# Symfony Doctrine ORM not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm just making a new Entity as usual, but something goes wrong and console report this error and I couldn't generate the entity setter/getter:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                              
Class "AppBundle\Entity\Admin_Actions" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Here is my Entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="admin_actions")
 */
class Admin_Actions
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="uid",type="string",length=100)
     */
    private $uid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="type",type="integer")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="linedate",type="datetime")
     */
    private $linedate;
}
```

If I do `doctrine:mapping:info`:

```
[Exception]                                                                                           
  You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have  
   entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.
```

I've just waste an hour trying to investigate the problem and I've already tried to rewrite it from new but I'm missing something. What's wrong with this?

Comment: 1. Make sure it is in `src/AppBundle/Entity/Admin_Actions.php` (check for case sensitivity aswell) 2. Clear the cache: `php app/console cache:clear` (use `bin/console` if you're on symfony 2.8+) 3. Are you using composers autoload map? If so, regenerate it: `composer dump-autoload -a`

Comment: Make sure you don't have any old mapping files lurking under AppBundle/Resurces/config/doctrine

Comment: I've just tried all the 4 points you wrote, nothing changed, the other entities work if I try to validate or update schema

Comment: Worked fine for me just copy/pasting your entity, so the problem's got to be elsewhere. Try deleting / renaming your whole cache folder maybe? What's the output of `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` ?

Comment: Check the place where you reference new entity for typos. The problem is usually not in the entity itself, but in the entity with has an association to the new one.

Comment: It is also possible that the underscore in your class name might be causing problems.  Doctrine does do some camel case to underscore transforming by default.  You should get rid of it regardless.

Comment: I've removed the underscore but nothing changed, now all my entities aren't working. All are not mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be datetime field has same name as function/implementation in doctrine, I  have got same mistake by naming a table "condition" which may be condition function in MySql query

Comment: I've updated it changing name, but nothing change, since now the others entities isn't working I think the problem is in another part

Comment: show your "Resource" file content, you cannot have both xml and annotation mapping

Comment: The problem was in Resource directory, Symfony has generated a file called Admin.orm.php that broke everything, when I delete this file all the entities come back to work. Thanks, I've never had this problem